# What is symmetry in this context?

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, polarization, adiabatic, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I'm reading a paper that was written by a senior undergraduate at my college and I'm having a trouble trying to understand a part of his paper. His paper is on Measuring nonlinear Phase accumulation for cyclic and non-cyclic Adiabatic transformation of the polarization state of light. In the paper he states

> *"In the context of a unit circle, Berry showed that what might seem like nothing more than a cyclic path parameterized by cosine and sine between 0 and 2π, or a cyclic transformation of state, is indeed much more than just that"*

He then translated the above statement as,

> *"In other words, the symmetry of outputs on a cyclic path is broken for systems that require more dimensions to describe their state than they have parameters"*

My question is, what is symmetry in this paper? Is it similar to the concept of symmetry in quantum mechanics? I realized that the physics in the paper is classical so I assumed that it has a different definition. The author doesn't bring the concept of symmetry again so it was hard to see the whole idea clearly.

The author then introduces an equation

$$ \overrightarrow{E}(z,t)= \overrightarrow{E_0}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$$

using the definition "...the symmetry of outputs on a cyclic path is broken for
systems that require more dimensions to describe their state than they have
parameters" Can we conclude that an electromagnetic wave is not symmetric?

It is silly to go to conclusion with out knowing the definition of symmetry so I apologize in advance.

Comment: Have you read other sources about the [Berry phase](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_phase)?

Comment: @rob I haven't used all my resources but yes I did look through some resources on the internet.